# Sequelize Op.or order by exact match first

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sequelize.js

I have a airports table with every row containing following fields: IATA, city, country... How can I search for all of these fields but return the results with the exact match first? For example if I type ALB, I want to see first result as ALB, Albany, USA and then all other matches rather than TIA, Tirana, Albania and Albany after that?

Here is my code:

```
const airports = await Airport.findAll({
      attributes: [
        'IATA',
        'city',
        'country',
      ],
      where: {
        [sequelize.Op.or]: [
          { IATA: filter.toUpperCase() },
          { city: { [sequelize.Op.like]: `%${filter}%` } },
          { country: { [sequelize.Op.like]: `%${filter}%` } },
        ],
        status: 1,
      },
});
```

Comment: Do you need list ALL that like the filters that you listed and order the data according to proximity with exact term on the filters?

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes exactly

Comment: Actually I care only about ordering the exact match for IATA first (if there is any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a related problem with this approach. I created a column on `order` that returns 1 if is a exact match on `IATA` like else `2`. Ordering this column will solve your problem.

As your column could be different and using `literal()`, you may adapt the order property but the concept is this.

```
const airports = await Airport.findAll({
      attributes: [
        'IATA',
        'city',
        'country',
      ],
      where: {
        [sequelize.Op.or]: [
          { IATA: filter.toUpperCase() },
          { city: { [sequelize.Op.like]: `%${filter}%` } },
          { country: { [sequelize.Op.like]: `%${filter}%` } },
        ],
        status: 1,
      },
      order: {
         [
           sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN `IATA` like '%${filter}%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END',
           'desc'
         ],
         ['city', 'desc']
      }
});
```

In my purpose, I got 4 `CASE`s and worked very well.

Obs: If your model have `alias` on column `IATA`, here, you need to put your original column name, as we building an literal term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also found this solution online and tried to implement it but I get this error: "SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'ALB' in 'order clause'" when I search for ALB for example

Comment: With certain changes in syntax this actually did work, thanks!

Comment: is there a way to add secondary ordering by another column? For example, primary order should be by exact IATA code and secondary by let's say city name, in alphabetic order?

Comment: I added a secondary order on answer. Take a look if it is. First order by IATA codes. If you have the same IATA code, order by city. If I understood your need.